# Access Gmail using the Gmail SDK with accessToken?

Tags: java, gmail, access-token

I am following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) to build a Android application which requests the user for Account access with Gmail Scope as Read Only and then generates a **authCode** and sends it to the backend server.

The backend server then receives the authCode and generates a **acessToken** using it. Here's the code for that:

```
private static String CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "/client_secret.json";

private static String REDIRECT_URI = "";

String accessToken = null;

// Exchange auth code for access token
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.class.newInstance(),
                new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE));

GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(),
                JacksonFactory.class.newInstance(), "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(), clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(), authCode,
                REDIRECT_URI).execute();

accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
```

Now using this access token the backend server needs to access **Gmail** using the Gmail SDK.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation for several hours I finally figured it out:

```
static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "POC";

/**
* Global instance of the JSON factory.
*/
static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

public Gmail getGmailService(String accessToken) throws IOException {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}
```

Using this Gmail Object you can then make further requests.